# JSON server suggestion on linux platforms

Tags: linux, json, rest, mobile

I need to create a JSON service to get and post data from a local and remote http/https server on Linux for my mobile apps. -I'm using MySQL as DB engine- 
I tried with Glassfish EJB/JSP (I like Java), but it was a kind of frustrating, due the poor support that my linux development machine (mint 13) has for Oracle Glassfish.

In your opinion, what is the best way to make a remote JSON server on that environment? which alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to accept and send back JSON, you want a [JAX-RS](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html)-based service, not a JSP one.

You will most likely use [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/), [RESTEasy](https://www.jboss.org/resteasy/), [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/restful-services.html), or similar implementations of the JAX-RS specification.

Sending back JSON from a JAX-RS implementation is trivial; that's what JAX-RS is designed to do.  Generally speaking, JSP is used for web applications (where HTML, CSS, images, and JavaScript are returned), while JAX-RS is used for RESTful web services, where JSON, XML, and YAML is returned.  You *can* use JSP to produce JSON, but it is not common.

As far as your overall architecture is concerned, any webserver is fine (Apache, Tomcat, etc.) and you can use either Springframework or a full app server like JBoss or Glassfish.  Springframework has its own REST support, but I've used JAX-RS several times with Spring and it works very well.  Since you already are using Glassfish, integrating a JAX-RS implementation should be straightforward. [This article from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ggnzk/index.html) shows you how.

Comment: Sounds great. Is there any open source http server for supporting JAX-RS? I think the Java EE 6 documentation is based on glassfish, and I could not to install it on linux.

Comment: Yes, I've used Tomcat (webserver) + Spring (application framework) + Jersey (JAX-RS).  All open source.  I mentioned Glassfish in my answer because it seemed that you are familiar with it, but I would recommend Spring :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you need to find a good framework where you feel confident.

I use Zend PHP + Doctrine to serve my apps. Why? I just create simple controllers in a good MVC like Zend  and use all power from Doctrine to handle queries. Ok, but why? Because I develop quick and neat code on it.

Best

Comment: I thought to switch to PHP for a while. I know about the advantages. I think I'll give it a chance on the next projects. Thank you.